# Batch script to keep asking for username until correct user name is entered

Tags: authentication, batch-file, cmd

I am not good with writing batch scripts, but here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to execute some sql (oracle) scripts from command prompt, but script cannot be run by one particular user name. So, whenever I want to run a script as that particular user name, I should see a message "Cannot Login As USER" and prompted to re-enter the user name. And this should continue till any other username is entered. I have the below script so far. Please help. Please ignore my poor batch scripting skills. :)

```
@ECHO OFF
Echo.
SET /P uname=Username:
IF %uname% == "notallowed" GOTO :LOGIN_ERROR GOTO :LOGIN

:LOGIN_ERROR
ECHO Username Cannot Be notallowed
SET /P uname=Username:
IF %uname% == "notallowed" GOTO :LOGIN_ERROR GOTO :LOGIN

:LOGIN
echo.
SET /P pass=Password:
echo.
SET /P mydatabase=Database:
echo.
rem set oracle_sid=ins
sqlplus -s %uname%/%pass%@%mydatabase% 
@C:/My_Folder/test.sql \n
sqlplus exit
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I hope you're not looking for any security though...

Comment: Please show the issue making user name ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@ECHO OFF

:GET_USER
ECHO.
SET /P uname=Username:
IF %uname%==notallowed (
  ECHO Username Cannot Be notallowed
  GOTO GET_USER
)

REM The rest of the script...
```

Comment: That would only check if the name equals "notallowed" and otherwise continue. To allow only particular usernames he'd have to keep prompting for a username as long as `%uname%` does not match a valid name.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what he is asking for. In this question, he says "but script cannot be run by one particular user name".

Comment: The subject OTOH clearly states that the script should keep prompting until a correct username is entered.

Comment: I agree, with correct meaning any other username than the one that is not allowed. From his question, "And this should continue till any other username is entered."

Answer (score 0):

Use an If statement and add goto "marker." example.

```
:login
set /p username=
If %username% == "CorrectUsername" goto next
GOTO login
:next
'Rest of your code goes below.
```